# Using multiple UNION ALL statements in WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE gyerek (
    gyereke INT,
    szulonek INT
);
```

I'm trying to use multiple `UNION ALL` statements in my `WITH` clause:

```
WITH testver (x, y) AS (
    SELECT gy1.gyereke, gy2.gyereke
    FROM gyerek gy1, gyerek gy2
    WHERE gy1.szulonek = gy2.szulonek
    AND gy1.gyereke <> gy2.gyereke
), rokon (x, y) AS (
    SELECT * FROM testver
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT r1.x, gy1.gyereke
    FROM rokon r1, gyerek gy1
    WHERE r1.y = gy1.szulonek)
    UNION ALL(SELECT gy1.gyereke, r1.y
    FROM rokon r1, gyerek gy1
    WHERE r1.x = gy1.szulonek)
)
SELECT * FROM rokon;
```

I get the following error:

`ORA-32041: UNION ALL operation in recursive WITH clause must have only two branches`

My **question** is: Is there a way to use multiple `UNION ALL` statements? If there isn't how can I achieve the unification of the last two `SELECT` statements.

Comment: And what do you expect from this query? I believe it could be written so easier, and by the way if it worked it would have returned duplicate records. Is it what you desired?

Comment: Do you really need `UNION ALL`? Doesn't `SELECT r1.x, gy1.gyereke FROM rokon r1 join gyerek gy1 ON gy1.szulonek IN (r1.x, r1.y)` suffice?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to rewrite `Datalog` rules to `SQL`. I don't know if it'd be an easier way, I've recently started learning the language and I've wondered why I'm not able to use multiple `UNION ALL`s.

Comment: You are creating a recursive `WITH` clause. You do know that, yes? A recursive `WITH` clause consists of <anker part> UNION ALL <recursive part>. The second `UNION ALL` is out of place.

Comment: I knew that is a recursive `WITH` clause. But I have three conditions in `Datalog` that is why I have three `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recursion you want to go on with `x` on a `y` match and with `y` on an `x` match. Use `CASE WHEN` to check which one matches.

```
, rokon (x, y) AS (
  SELECT x, y FROM testver
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE WHEN gy1.szulonek = r1.x THEN r1.y ELSE r1.x END, gy1.gyereke
  FROM rokon r1
  JOIN gyerek gy1 ON gy1.szulonek IN (r1.x, r1.y)
)
```